# Filling in gaps between polygons using PostGIS functions

Tags: postgis, convex-hull

I have a similar question to [Filling gaps between polygons using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293695/filling-gaps-between-polygons-using-qgis)

The solution talks about using it in QGIS but I want to use PostGIS functions on a table on the geometry column.

The solution talks about convex hull but not sure how to use the convex_hull PostGIS function here. I want to fill the gap by moving/merging the gap to the neighboring polygon.

Comment: Check the last example of the [`convex hull documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) this should be exactly what you want.